# How to change python launch command in PyCharm

Tags: python, macos, pycharm

If I directly run start.py, I get:

```
Symbol not found: _OCIAttrGet
Referenced from: /Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/cx_Oracle.so
```

After some googling, I found that its because Oracle client arch issues. I now run my script like this and it works:

```
arch -i386 python2.7 start.py
```

Now with a free edition of PyCharm available (thank you JetBrains), I imported my projects but how do I set the "Run Configuration" to launch my script the way I do it from terminal.

I tried:

```
Run -> Edit Configuration -> Python Interpreter but it is already populated with the known python paths

Run -> Edit Configuration -> Interpreter Options but throws an error saying unknown file "arch"
```

Any workarounds?